# Summation of a series ,

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does the series below have a closed form 
$(1 + a^2 + a^6  + \cdots + a^{2^n} - 2 + \cdots)$
It is given that $0 < a < 1.$
I have tried attempting this question but I'm not able to make any progress 
Kindly help.

Comment: Hint: Check geometric series in the special case that $|r|<1$. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: @HR-Physics it is not a geometric series since the ratio of two consecutive terms depends on 'n'

Comment: @infinitylord this is a part of a bigger question where I got stuck I'll edit the question in a minute for more info

Comment: @TobyMak: How is this a geometric series?  It is not of the form $c+cr+cr^2+cr^3+\cdots$.  If it is, what are $c$ and $r$?

Comment: What makes you suspect that there is a closed form for the solution?

Comment: The answer is given at the back of the book as a closed form

Comment: @infinitylord check the question edit too

Comment: @syedsameedAhmed: Why did you change the exponent form back to $a^{2^n}$?  It no longer matches the initial terms.

Comment: Someone edited it and then I reeditted

Comment: @Brian Tung  check out the full version of question too

Comment: I edited it.  Your re-edit no longer makes sense.  However, it doesn't matter because you somehow made an error in deriving your expression.  The original problem should in fact yield a geometric series.  Each radius is to the previous radius by a constant ratio.  Find the ratio, and you have your sum.

Comment: You should check the derivation of your series. In reality, it has to be a geometric series with the quotiont $\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{2}+1}\right)^2$, because the radii form a geometric sequence with ratio $\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{2}+1}\right)^2$. So the final result will be

Comment: @Brian Tung Ok thank you and sorry for inconvenience

Comment: @ProfessorVector: The radii have that ratio?  Or the areas do?

Comment: @Brian Tung I wonder whether the series above has a closed form what are your views

Comment: So the general term is $a^{2n-2}$. You edited to $a^{2n} -2$ which doesn't reflect the exponent sequence $0 ,2 ,6,...$.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: the areas have the ratio $\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{2}+1}\right)^2$, because the radii have the ratio $\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{2}+1}$.

Comment: If we call the (original) series $F(a)$, then $F(a) = 1+a^2F(a^2)$. I haven't gotten further than that.

Comment: @Zubzub The series above Is wrong because it doesn't come up if u solve the original question below. However I wonder whether the series has a closed form. Sorry for the inconvenience that my miscalculation may have caused.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution to the problem you were trying to do:**

Draw 2 circles on the $xy$ axis with radii $R_n$ and $R_{n+1}$ following the conditions described in the problem. Then draw a line connecting the centers of the two circles, and make a right isocelece triangle out of that with the line being the hypotenuse.

Notice that hypotenuse has length $R_n + R_{n+1}$ and the sides have length $R_n - R_{n+1}$. The pythagorean theorem tells us that the hypotenuse then also has length $\sqrt{2}(R_n - R_{n+1}) $, implying
$$R_n + R_{n+1} = \sqrt{2}(R_n - R_{n+1})$$
$$R_{n+1} (1 + \sqrt {2}) = R_n (\sqrt {2} - 1)$$
$$R_{n+1} = \frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{\sqrt {2}+1} R_n = r R_n$$
So the total area is 
$$\sum \pi R_n^2 = \pi \
R_1^2 \sum r^{2n} = \pi R_1^2 \sum (r^2)^n $$
Which is a geometric series

As for solving $\sum a^{2^n-2}$, I have no idea, nor can I guarantee it has a closed form